# Javascript - if statement with several conditions in shorthand notation

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have several if statements in my script which require a lot of conditions and I would like to write them in the more efficient way and with "shorthand notation" for the readability.

For example, I have this if statement:

```
if (x === 'abc' || x === 'def' || x === 'ghi' || x ==='jkl') {
    /*** some code ***/
}
```

So I have written it in with indexOf and array but i'm not sure if it's the best way:

```
if (['abc', 'def', 'ghi' ,'jkl'].indexOf(x) > -1) {
   /*** some code ***/
}
```

I'm near sure there are some other methods more cleaner and fastest...

Comment: What you have looks best.

Comment: you could alternatively do a `switch`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I can't replace with 'abcd', it was just for the example. And if I use a /(a|b|c|d)/.test(x), is it better or the same?

Comment: if you have to find many times, use key value will be more erricient

Comment: I think the switch statement would be neater.  With this `if (['abc', 'def', 'ghi' ,'jkl'].indexOf(x) > -1)` You have to create an additional array then discard it right away, so performance-wise, not good. I think switch would be a better choice.

Comment: you keep moving the goalpost on what your values are. If you want a definitive answer on what's most efficient, post *real* examples of your values

Comment: hmm, i think the if statement you have already give you the best performance and readability.

Comment: In the examples you have, I prefer the array - it is more succinct and better communicates intent: readers read "x is in this set of values" instead of "a is x or b is x or c is x or d is x..." It will also scale much better for larger sets of values. It surprises me that some people seem to think the multiple or clauses are more readable. Worrying about performance here is premature.

Comment: In my opinion it also looks more readable with an array. I was also thinking about `/(a|b|c|d)/.test(x)` but I think it's a little bit dirty and it doesn't have the same purpose...

Comment: Also, context is important here - you have reduced the scenario to something so narrow and fake that it's really impossible to know if suggestions will make sense for the real code. Bear that in mind when evaluating answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The if statement compares strings mainly and only contains one if, so a switch can't be used or is useful

Comment: how about shorthand for this? ```if (x === 'abc' && x === 'def' && x === 'ghi' && x ==='jkl') {
    /*** some code ***/
}```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array is readable and easy to modify. It also gives you the ability to take the array as a parameter if you later chose to do so.

If you're using ES6, you may want to use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'].includes(x)) {
   /*** some code ***/
}
```

Worrying about performance in this case would be a premature optimization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the useful tip about ES6 `.include()`. I will certainly use it later.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question of readability. What will make the most sense when you're reading the same code in five months?

```
x === 'a' || x === 'b' || x === 'c' || x ==='d'
```

or

```
['a', 'b', 'c' ,'d'].indexOf(x) > -1
```

I would use the long 'or' expression, since it very clearly and explicitly tells you what the code is doing. However, I'd wrap that expression in a function to make the rest of the code more readable

Example:

```
isSpecialLetter = function (x){
  return x === 'a' || x === 'b' || x === 'c' || x ==='d';
}

if(isSpecialLetter(x)){
//More code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use ES5 then

`if(~['abc', 'def', 'ghi' ,'jkl'].indexOf(x)) {...}`

or a bit more expressive

`if(!!~['abc', 'def', 'ghi' ,'jkl'].indexOf(x)) {...}`